# Userform Password unhide worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have worksheet which is named("Dates"), I want this worksheet to be hidden and only be visible through a password. Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False / True.

I have a userform set-up. Below is the code i have behind my form.

[image]

```
Private passwordStatus As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String
    Dim Password As String

    a = "123"
    Password = TextBox1.Text
    'Set Pawwordstatus at False before Testing
    passwordStatus = False
    If Password = a Then
        MsgBox "Password Correct.", vbInformation
        passwordStatus = True
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Function checkPassword() As Boolean
  UserForm1.Show
  'Shows the User Form. And after Closing the Form
  'The PasswordStatus Value will be returned and you can check if
  'it is true
  checkPassword = passwordStatus
End Function
```

**Problem:** I am not sure what code to write behind my worksheet event that each time a user attempts to access this worksheet the userform is shown and password requested for access.

I have this code behind **thisworkbook:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Worksheets("Dates").Visible = False

    'must save, if not save, it is not effect.
    Me.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in a standard `Module` declare public variables

```
Public LastActiveSht As Worksheet
Public IsPassword As Boolean
```

Then in `ThisWorkBook` module add

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set LastActiveSht = Sh
End Sub

Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Dates" Then
        LastActiveSht.Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        IsPassword = False
        UserForm1.Show
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Your `CommandButton1_Click` for `UserForm1` seems okay but I've changed it a bit as

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String

    a = "aaa"
    Password = TextBox1.Text
    If Password = a Then
        MsgBox "Password Correct.", vbInformation
        IsPassword = True
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, to handle when user clicks on the `CLOSE` button of UserForm1, add following code in `USERFORM` module

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If IsPassword Then LstSht.Activate
End Sub
```

***NOTE :*** Using above you don't have to hide the sheet or make it invisible but every time sheet `Dates` is selected, correct password has to be entered.

Comment: Perfect thanks for that.I am getting an error of "object required" on LstSht.Activate in thisworkbook.

Comment: @James - Oopa! my mistake. `LstSht.Activate` should be `LastActiveSht.Activate`

Answer (score 1):

Use the workbook before save event to set the visible property of the given worksheet to xlVeryHidden and in the workbook open event show your password form and if the password is correct unhide the sheet.

That way it gets hidden when you save the file and only made visible to a user with the password on open.

Answer (score 0):

This is the call for the Password form. Install it on the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the button (ActiveX control). It reacts to the click of CommandButton1 (which I would give a meaningful name, such as `CmdPassword`)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim PwForm As UserForm1
    Dim a As String
    Dim Password As String

    Set PwForm = New UserForm1
    With PwForm
        .Tag = Password
        .Show
        If .Tag = 1 Then
            ' show & activate (select) the hidden sheet
        End If
    End With
    Unload PwForm
    Set PwForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code calls the function `Password` which is given below. Install it on the same code sheet as the above procedure.

```
Private Function Password() As String
    ' 03 Sep 2017

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim PwArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    PwArr = Array(80, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100)
    For i = 0 To UBound(PwArr)
        Fun = Fun & Chr(PwArr(i))
    Next i
    Password = Fun
End Function
```

You see a mild attempt to disguise the password. The array is created by the sub `CallCreatePassword`. This and the function `CreatePassword` which it calls need not be part of your project. You can keep this code elsewhere. Wherever it is, it should be on a standard code module, with the function it calls below it.

```
Private Sub CallCreatePassword()
    ' 03 Sep 2017

    ' ===================================================
    ' Use this sub to call the CreatePassword sub
    ' which will print a string of numbers to the Immediate window.
    ' Paste that string into the PwArr array in the function Password
    ' ===================================================

    CreatePassword ("Password")             ' enter the password of your choice
End Sub

Private Sub CreatePassword(ByVal Pw As String)
    ' 03 Sep 2017

    Dim Fun() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim Fun(0 To Len(Pw) - 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(Pw)
        Fun(i - 1) = Asc(Mid(Pw, i, 1))
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(Fun, " ,")
End Sub
```

Back to the Click_procedure. There the password is written to the form's `Tag` property before showing that form. With the `Show` command control is passed to the Userform. The code in this proc will continue to run only after a `Hide` command from the UserForm.

The userform should have two buttons (not just one like yours). Both include the `Hide` command, but they set either 1 or 0 to the `Tag` property. Both these procedures must be installed on the code sheet of Userform1.

```
Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()

    Tag = ""
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CmdOK_Click()
    ' 03 Sep 2017

    With TextBox1
        If .Text = Tag Then
            Tag = 1
            Hide
        Else
            MsgBox "This password is not correct." & vbCr & _
                   "Press ""Cancel"" to exit."
            .Text = ""
            .SetFocus
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

After the form is hidden, the click procedure continues. If the Tag's value = 1 (that is a string, actually), the hidden worksheet is made visible and activated. Else it doesn't. In either case, the procedure ends.

You may wish to add an event procedure which fires Before_Close to make the sheet VeryHidden again.

Comment: thanks for the code above. Is this whole code going behind my userform?

Comment: I am getting on error on this code of : Automation error:The callee (server{not server application}) is not availsble and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may have executed. "If .Tag = 1 Then"

Comment: I have added installation instructions to my above answer.